# Cannot connect to Ubuntu LTS from another network

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, ssh, firewall

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on VirtualBox (Windows) with DHCP ip configuration. In other words, I haven't configured anything. Well, I HAVE updated all packages and installed ssh server and midnight commander. Anyway here's the issue: I'm using VirtualBox to learn using Linux and terminal-based operating systems in general. And from what I've heard, being able to connect to your server from another network is as basic as it gets. But here's the thing. I can only connect to my server by either securing an ssh from PuTTY and CMD on the computer VirtualBox is running on, or from any other device that is connected to the same router as my server. I saw a few guides in YouTube and here on askubuntu and they said it was an issue with the firewall. But I have allowed port 22/tcp in my firewall and that is the reason I can connect to my server from devices on the same network.
Long story short, I want to know if there is anything you have to do to specifically allow other networks to connect to your server. I read somewhere that I have to configure the `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` files, but don't exactly know why and how I should do that.

Comment: Since you CAN connect from other machines on your local network, you have seem to have demonstrated that your Ubuntu server is set up properly. Most likely, your external connections are being blocked by your router (not an Ubuntu issue). Look up how to how to use your router's features to permit access: "port forwarding", "DMZ", and "VPN" are three popular ways to do it. Remember also that ALL devices on your local network share the *same* external IP address (that's why you have a router and a local network).

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll try port forawrding and report back to you

Comment: hi @user535733, I know I took a long while. But I have my reasons. Any way, I just wanted to say that I searched the internet a bit to learn about port forwarding and I found out that I am not able to do port forwarding, since I don't have access to the router I'm connected to. I also read about something called reverse ssh port forwarding? At any rate, I have no idea what any of these stuff means. So I would REAAAALY appreciate it if you would help me out a bit!

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help you. There are many good tutorials out there on networking and ssh and reverse ssh. You are asking about a rather complex networking task that you will have to maintain - you must do some homework about exactly what you want and how to safely do it. There are no shortcuts here.

Comment: Okay... at least I know I'm on the right path now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around port forwarding it seems. For anyone else who has this problem: do your homework on basic networking like I did and you'll understand why this is a really stupid idea. Also, the comments on my question were really helpfull, too. So check them out as well.